# Functional Calculus in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, variational-calculus, correlation-functions, functional-derivatives

Does anybody know some good sources with detailed derivations of the main results we need to compute generating functionals in QFT (and functional calculus used in the subject in general). I find that in mainstream books, such as Peskin and Schroeder Chapter 9, the details are glanced over, and that there are some "hidden" product or chain rules that I would like to get a better grasp of. Note: I'm aware of the product and chain rules for functional derivatives, I'd just like to see more detailed examples with explanations of their application.

Comment: Maybe you should try Atland and Simons "Condensed Matter Field Theory". I am fully aware that there is "Condesed Matter" in the title, but it has a lot of the same stuff you need...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this might sound a bit odd at first, I particularly recommend Nivaldo Lemos' book [*Analytical Mechanics*](https://doi.org/10.1017/9781108241489).

In Chapter 10, it deals with classical field theory, and in order to do so the author chooses to deal with a bit of functional calculus. When doing so,he provides some more detail on the definition of functional derivative than most QFT books I've seen and provides some more examples. This contrasts a bit with P&S's approach of defining the functional derivative in terms of Dirac deltas and pretty much just imposing the main results. Lemos doesn't spend a lot of time on functional derivatives, but does provide some examples and I find it more clear than most other texts.

[This answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/677554/168783) to another post might also provide an example of application of functional derivatives in field theory.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look.

Comment: While the book does provide a very nice introduction I was also hoping to see some examples (with the relevant special cases) of the functional chain rule. This really seems to be brushed over or taken for granted in a lot of text books.